# In vb .net - placing multiple controls inside layoutTablePane "cell"

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

In the layout I'm writing, there's an area where a different control is shown, depending on various conditions.

Can I place all of these controls at design-time, or I must "re-attach" and "remove" each control at runtime?

Comment: `there's an area` --> Where you are going to place the controls.?

Comment: inside the same "cell". i'd like to shape each alternative control and it's properties, to see how it would look like in its layout, sizes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host a panel inside a TableLayoutPanel cell. Or any other control container. In that you can put as many controls as you want.

For example, you could use a nested FlowLayoutPanel. So you may not need to manually perform layout management.